# What version of PostgreSQL first implemented autovacuum?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum

I'm just wondering what version of PostgreSQL first implemented autovacuum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to [PostgreSQL 8.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/release-8-1.html) it was an extension; 8.1 moved autovacuum into the distribution and away from `pg_autovacuum`, from the release notes

> Move `/contrib/pg_autovacuum` into the main server (Alvaro)
>
> Integrating autovacuum into the server allows it to be automatically started and stopped in sync with the database server, and allows autovacuum to be configured from `postgresql.conf`.

But concurrent vacuuming and enabled-by-default [`autovacuum` was introduced in 8.3,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/release-8-3.html)

> Autovacuum is now enabled by default (Alvaro)
>
> Several changes were made to eliminate disadvantages of having autovacuum enabled, thereby justifying the change in default. Several other autovacuum parameter defaults were also modified.